# FCM Push notification not receiving on iOS mobile devices

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have created a Cordova project and implemented an FCM push notification.

Platform added:

- android 6.3.0
- ios: 4.5.5

FCM plugin installed:

- cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependency-update

FCM push notification working fine with the FCM console. Can generate token and receive push message for **android**.

Tried to push via [testing server](https://cordova-plugin-fcm.appspot.com) for ios, but no push message received on the device.

Implementation:

1. using apple developer account new bundle id created with push notification feature
2. configured CSR certificate and downloaded provisional profile
3. Using downloaded profile ios project bundled
4. FCM account created and configured with .p12 (exported from mac keychain access)
5. From FCM `GoogleService-Info.plist` copied in Cordova project root folder
6. Installed `cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependency-update` plugin
7. X-Code: project > target > capabilities enabled Push Notification **ON**
8. X-Code: menu File > Project settings > Build System selected as "**Legacy Build System**"
9. In device ready handler, device token taken
10. Exported IPA and installed the device
11. Try to trigger push using test server not receiving a push notification on the device

In javascript used `FCMPlugin.onNotification` API to receive the message.

Via triggered push by backend java code getting below IOException in catch,

> java.io.ioexception getsecretkey failed pbe secretkeyfactory not
>   available

Comment: Bro it worked? Because I am facing same issues with IOS. Working fine with Android.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs